# Excel formula to find and goto cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have a formula that's part of a conditional formatting rule that highlights in green any cell that contains whatever text I type. It works great but I have to scroll to find the row. Is there a way to have the formula goto that cell so I don't have to scroll down.

This is the formula: `=SEARCH(input,$B2&$C2&$D2&$E2)`

Comment: I think formula - is something you calculate and put to the cell value. To achieve what you need - you need to use scripting, VBA. How to use VBA - is outside of scope of this question.

Comment: I'm not a programmer but I think what I'm asking can be achieved without using VBA. Take a look at how this guy uses several functions together to do a NAME lookup and display the results at the top of the page. Note he doesn't rely on VBA whatsoever, but he is clever with how he strings several functions together, it's a work of art. 

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/05/14/lookup-with-multiple-criteria-and-display-multiple-search-results-using-excel-formula/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In MS Excel, there's possibility find and select cells that meet specific conditions, here's [the manual on office support](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Find-and-select-cells-that-meet-specific-conditions-2d686424-6150-4015-a8e4-a5990f4d7e3a).
2. If you know how to use Excel **VBA**, you may create the script, which will do the job, and to bind it to some shortcut or button:

   ```
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Your sheet").Columns(1).Find("Text to search").Select
   ```
3. And the third possibility to "go to specific cell" which I've found is [described here](https://superuser.com/questions/440449/go-to-specific-row-number-in-excel).
4. Possibly you may adapt for your needs [CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc), which does the selection of up to 254 values based on the index number.

Comment: @Emzor and Farside,

Thanks for your replies. All this stuff is over my head gents, you really have to how they say "dumb it down" for me. lol

Comment: @Superfast, what do you mean? None of these variants fit your need? o_O I doubt there are any other variants to accomplish your task, I'm kind of a experienced guy in Excel, can't think of any better cases.

Comment: What I want to do is this:

1. Type a name into a cell
2. Have Excel search column A for that name
3. If found, have that row appear on top of the page

I don't know how to code this and don't know where to put the code to make it happen. I do appreciate the replies I got so far. 

Thanks everybody for trying to help I give up I have a headache now. lol

Comment: Haha, @Superfast, what kind of input have you expected to get from Stackoverflow - site for professional and enthusiast **programmers**? As the thank you can at least up-vote/accept someones request, which you found useful. To give up - is not a good idea, find the solution :)

Comment: LOL @Farside

No hard feelings man it's no big deal really but thanks guys for trying to help a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Not a formula per se, but if it is the only conditional fomatting, you could hit F5, click "special", select "conditional formats" and click "ok"

Comment: Thanks for your reply Fred but that didn't come close to what I'm looking for.  I just want to do a simple text search and have the result display at the top of the page.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are looking for.   Perhaps a sample of expected input and output would help.   If you are just trying to find the first cell that contains that input and they are all in the same row, as your OP suggests, why can't you just use a match function?

Comment: Yes Fred I just want to find the first cell that contains the input. I want to type something like "WebMD" then have Excel bring up that row so I don't have to scroll down to find it.. Right now I have to scroll wayyyyyy down to find "WebMD" because I have over 1000 rows of data.

I apologize Fred but I don't know anything about Functions or VBA or anything to do with programming. I was hoping someone could write something then show me how to set it up in Excel.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: There is no way to have a formula scroll down the page.   Possible solution would be to use formulas to basically produce a copy of that row.  It is more difficult than you think,  though.   Also,  the input would have to be in the same column every time.   Is this what you need or must it account for input in any column?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a formula, I only mentioned formula because that's what I found on another website to do the search part. I was thinking that someone could just improve on the formula I already had but if there are other ways to achieve it what I'm trying to do then by all means feel free to share it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I got from the Microsoft Office forums.

```
Public Sub FindRecords()
Dim sFalse As String
Dim iDay As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

sFalse = "False"

iDay = InputBox("Enter the value you want to scroll to:")

'   Test if input box is empty or cancel is pressed
If iDay = vbNullString Or iDay = sFalse Then GoTo ExitOut

i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

On Error GoTo Notfound

j = Range("A3:A" & i).Find(what:=iDay, after:=Range("A3")).Row
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = j
Exit Sub

Notfound:
MsgBox "Your value was not found."
Exit Sub

ExitOut:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to format code properly in your answer.